# Rails 5.2 - Active Storage - Too slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

First of all, I'm new on Rails and my English isn't that great, so please bear with me :)

I updated my Rails for the 5.2 version and installed the active storage. I can upload images or attachments and that's working well. The problem is when I try to get the images, they take about 30sec-60sec just to appear on the screen. That's not normal, so for sure I did something wrong.

My installation process was the follow:

rails active_storage:install

rails db:migrate

'schema':

```
create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name", null: false
  t.string "record_type", null: false
  t.integer "record_id", null: false
  t.integer "blob_id", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
  t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
end

create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "key", null: false
  t.string "filename", null: false
  t.string "content_type"
  t.text "metadata"
  t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
  t.string "checksum", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
 end
```

'storage.yml':

```
local:
 service: Disk
 root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

On 'config/environments/development.rb':

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

After that I updated my model:

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :model
 belongs_to :manufacturer
 has_and_belongs_to_many :features

 has_one_attached :banner_image
 has_many_attached :images
end
```

Then updated my params in the controller:

```
def vehicle_params
  params.require(:vehicle).permit(:date, :kms, :power, :cc, :version, :transmission, :fuel, :category, :seats, :doors, :color, :condition, :warranty, :manufacturer_id, :model_id, {feature_ids: []}, :banner_image, images: [])
end
```

Follow by my form:

```
<p>
  <span>Imagen de apresentação: </span>
  <%= f.file_field :banner_image %>
</p>

<p>
  <span>Imagens: </span>
  <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
</p>
```

And at last my index:

```
<% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
  <%= link_to "Editar", edit_vehicle_path(vehicle) %> |
  <%= link_to "X", vehicle, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Tem a certeza que quer eliminar este veiculo?"} %>
  <%= link_to vehicle do %>
    <% if vehicle.banner_image.attached? %>
      <%= image_tag (vehicle.banner_image) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= vehicle.manufacturer.name %> <%= vehicle.model.name %> <%= vehicle.version %>
  <hr />
<% end %>
```

I also installed Mini-Magick gem (and ImageMagick as required), but I'm not using it yet.

Versions:

- ImageMagick 6.8.9-9)
- Ruby 2.3.1p112
- Rails 5.2.0

Network tab:
As you can see, it take far too long to get the images.
[image: Network]

Logs: I also include the logs, but TBH I can't understand much there, so maybe you can detect something wrong.
[image: logs-part-1][image: logs-part-2][image: logs-part-3][image: logs-part-4]

I don't know if I didn't do something or if I did something wrong, but the truth is when I load my index page my images takes really long time to show up...

Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please dont post an images of code, post actual code.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question

Comment: Are the images perhaps taking a long time to load because they're very big files? Nothing about your code indicates to me that ruby/rails/active storage is the source of the problem.

Comment: All the images are between 60-200KB, so no :)

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in your browser when loading the page? Do you see what the bottleneck is? Assuming it's something in your rails application, which action specifically is it? What does the rails log say?

Comment: Hi again @TomLord, I added the logs in the description as the network tab. About the action, is just a index page that shows some vehicles images, scopes to filter that vehicles by manufacturer and model and the paths to edit and delete the same vehicles, nothing too complex.

Comment: Can you find the slow request in the log? It's not easy for me to even read that, since you've posted an image of the code (!!) and I can't use CTRL+F. Where are the requests that took 10+ seconds?

Comment: I'm sorry about the images, but please understand that I can't put so much code in here...it's already too long that description. About the logs, its weird because the times are normal..each request are all under 100ms, and in the most cases are like 40, 50 or 60 ms...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my config/environments/development.rb I had this command to not restart my server every time I change something on a controller: config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false

If I remove that line, everything works smooth (except when I change something in the controller I have to restart de server xD)

Best regards!